# How to prevent Windows 10 lock screen during batch processing?

Tags: batch-file, lockscreen

How can lock screen be prevented during long lasting batch file processing on Windows 10?

I can't find any command for use in batch files (command line).

Answer (score 1):

here you go

```
set wsc = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Do
    'Five minutes
    WScript.Sleep(5*60*1000)
    wsc.SendKeys("{F13}")
Loop
```

this will click F13 on your keyboard every 5 minute... since you don't have F13 on you keyboard, it will effectively have no other effects but to keep your screen from locking.

*Caveat - if you're using bash, it will key in ~ in it while you're using it. It's like pressing F12 while using bash. quite annoying at times.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no way to do this from the batch itself. Unfortunately, the lock screen can only be prevented from coming up by sending mouse or keyboard events. Batch can't simulate such events without involving other tools like VS-Script or Powershell.

I'd take [this](https://dmitrysotnikov.wordpress.com/2009/06/29/prevent-desktop-lock-or-screensaver-with-powershell/) PowerShell script. It will prevent lock screen for a desired duration.

You could completely convert your batch code to PowerShell or simply start the ps1 script from your batch before starting the actual work.

Comment: I will try [prevent-screensaver](http://poshcode.org/get/1182) and paste it into the batch before it starts.

Comment: That's a lot of code to run within the script. It works though: [code](PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""Prevent-Screensaver.ps1""' -Verb RunAs}")

Answer (score 0):

Paste this commands in a text editor of your choice and save it with the `.bat` file  extension. Then just run this batch file to prevent windows from locking your screen.

```
powercfg /change standby-timeout-dc 0
powercfg /change standby-timeout-ac 0
powercfg /change monitor-timeout-dc 0
powercfg /change monitor-timeout-ac 0
powercfg /change hibernate-timeout-dc 0
powercfg /change hibernate-timeout-ac 0
```

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way is to manually disable your screensaver before launching the batch.

Comment: That means a lot of work before running each time a batch. Is there at least a command that can be started when batch finished like the 'shutdown' command?